# Interpolation question

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a polynomial [image] such that

[image]

for *i* = 1, 2,..., *N* distinct nodes. How would I show that this possesses a unique solution and find a way of constructing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the interpolation polynomial for the derivative values, integrate, adjust value at $x_0$ by the integration constant.

Comment: Would this also show that the problem has a unique solution?

Comment: Yes, since at its base the interpolation problem is a linear system of equations for the coefficients of the polynomial. $n+1$ equations for $n+1$ coefficients. Examine the kernel of this system.